# What does C.N.B.L. on New Hampshire death certificate mean?

Tags: death-records, 1970s, new-hampshire

I am researching my grandmother. I have her death certificate from 1973, Nashua, NH. Under "Father's Name" and "Mother's Maiden Name" it says only C.N.B.L.

Does anyone have a suggestion about what that means?

My mother is listed as the "Informant". I know that she had been trying to find out more about her ancestors recently but I thought she would have known her grandparents' names.

Answer (score 4):

FamilySearch have a really useful page of [Acronyms and Abbreviations](https://www.familysearch.org/wiki/en/Acronyms_and_Abbreviations) on their Wiki.

In this case, for ***CNBL*** it has:

> Cannot Be Located